# Conditional Tag for Wishlist membership. If the user is added to two levels show particular content

Tags: user-roles, membership

I am currently using a plug-in called Wishlist member. It allows you to create membership levels in WordPress. I want to be able to display different content on a page depending on if the user is added to two levels.

Am using the code of "Bainternet":

// get the current user level from WP more important is global $user.
$user = wp_get_current_user();

// Get user levels from WishlistMembers
$levels = WLMAPI::GetUserLevels($user->ID);

//then run the check for the level you want like this:

if(in_array('silver', $levels)){

//  PRINT OUT THE silver LEVEL stuff here
}

elseif (in_array('gold', $levels)){

// PRINT OUT THE gold LEVEL stuff here
}

which works perfectly if the user is one level. If the user is added to two levels then how to use the above code? Please assist.

Regards,

Raghav.

Comment: Is there anybody to assist me? Please.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Does it work for a user who's only in gold, and also for one who's only in silver? Also, what happens (what output do you get) when the user is in both levels?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the latest version of WishList Member, it now has built-in API functions for stuff like this. Using those, you'd do this:

```
wp_get_current_user();

$gold_sku = 123456789;
$silver_sku = 987654321;
$user_id = $user->ID;

if ( wlmapi_is_user_a_member($gold_sku, $user_id) ) {
     //Do gold stuff here
} elseif ( wlmapi_is_user_a_member($silver_sku, $user_id) ) {
     //Do silver stuff here
}
```

If want to check that they belong to BOTH levels, do this:

```
if ( wlmapi_is_user_a_member($gold_sku, $user_id) && wlmapi_is_user_a_member($silver_sku, $user_id) ) {
     //Do gold AND silver stuff here
}
```

If you want to check that they belong to EITHER level, do this:

```
if ( wlmapi_is_user_a_member($gold_sku, $user_id) || wlmapi_is_user_a_member($silver_sku, $user_id) ) {
     //Do gold AND silver stuff here
}
```

You can check the Codex for this function here:

http://codex.wishlistproducts.com/function-reference-wlmapi_is_user_a_member/

Answer (score 0):

There was a plugin that was available to wishlist insider member called Wishlist Shortcodes Plus.

You can buy this plugin now but you need to register to wishlist insider community first.

If you want to read a review we made several months ago on this plugin at:

http://wishlistmemberplugins.net/wishlist-shortcode-plus